# How to remove a tool window from tool window bar in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

For example `Version Control` tool window. I never use it. I use version control support, but not this tool window itself. How can I remove it from tool window bar?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a plugin to hide certain tool windows
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1489

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to actually hide the button, but just don't want it in the way while looking for the buttons you do use regularly, you can always drag it to some side of the screen that you don't often use. (I rarely use the bottom-right, so I could move some things there.) That way, you don't see them when picking a tab, but you can still get to it if you need to. (And every once in a while, I suspect you may really want to look at that Version Control view.)